# Du'as for Invoking Allah

Tags: dua

Is it Permissible for me to Recite this Du'a "Allahumma Inni As'aluka Bi Anna Lakal Hamdu Laa Ilaaha Illah Antal Rabbil Aalaminar Rahmanir Rahim" Before Making Du'a i.e as a way of Invoking Allah.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Except with some mistakes in the transliteration why should it not be permissible?

Answer (score 1):

InshaAllah Yes. There are two parts to dua. First part is praising Allah and second part is asking your need. Just like Surah Fatiha.

> Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him,
> said, “Allah Almighty said: I have divided prayer between Myself and
> My servant into two halves, and My servant shall have what he has
> asked for. When the servant says, ‘All praise is due to Allah the Lord
> of the worlds,’ Allah says: My servant has praised Me. When he says,
> ‘The Gracious, the Merciful,’ Allah says: My servant has exalted Me.
> When he says, ‘The Master of the Day of Judgment,’ Allah says: My
> servant has glorified Me and my servant has submitted to Me. When he
> says, ‘You alone we worship, You alone we ask for help,’ Allah says:
> This is between Me and My servant, and My servant will have what he
> has asked for. When he says, ‘Guide us to the straight path, the path
> of those whom you have favored, not those who went astray,’ Allah
> says: This is for My servant, and My servant will have what he has
> asked for.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 395   Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to
> Muslim

Complete dua

> It was narrated that Anas bin Malik said: "I was sitting with the
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and a man was standing and praying. When he
> bowed, prostrated and recited the tashahhud, he supplicated, and in
> his supplication he said: "**Allahumma inni as'aluka bi-anna lakal-hamd,
> lailaha illa ant, al-mannanu badi'us-samawati wal-ard, ya dhal-jalali
> wal-ikram! Ya hayyu ya qayyum! Inni as'aluka**. (O Allah, indeed I ask
> You since all praise is due to You, there is none worthy of worship
> but You, the Bestower, the Creator of the heavens and earth, O
> Possessor of majesty and honor, O Ever-living, O-Eternal, I ask of
> You.)' The Prophet (ﷺ) said: 'Do you know what he has supplicated
> with?' They said: "Allah (SWT) and His Messenger know best." He said:
> 'By the One in Whose Hand is my soul, he called upon Allah by His
> greatest Name, which, if He is called by it, He responds, and if He is
> asked by it, He gives.'"
>
> Reference: Sunan an-Nasa'i 1300